# Remove all punctuation except "?" and "!"

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove all punctuation except the markers : "?" and "!"

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", "hi, i'm (john), nice to meet you !! Do you want some water ?// #")
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:](?|!)]", "", "your string")`

Comment: @RonakShah `[^[:alnum:][:space:]?!]` is enough unless you wish to exclude parentheses and pipe character. No need for an alternation within a character class.